# Android Feature Module VS Dynamic Feature Module

Tags: android, modularization

While researching about android modularization I've come across the term Dynamic Feature Module, however I've also noticed Feature Module.

What are the differences? I've seen a lot of articles about Dynamic Feature Module, however I can't seem to find documentation on Feature Module. I can't also seem to find a way to create a Feature Module in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

from 'On Demand Modules' codelab:

> Google Play's app serving model, called Dynamic Delivery, uses Android
> App Bundles to generate and serve optimized APKs for each user's
> device configuration, so users download only the code and resources
> they need to run your app

Dynamic features (or on demand modules or dynamic delivery) are basically 'optional' modules to the final user (modules that him can or not download depending on the conditions that you pre determined). [Dynamic Feature | On Demand Modules | Dynamic Delivery](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery#0)

'Common' android modularization is basically a way to organize your code base by contained parts and coupled with flexibility. Each part is a module.
[Android developers modularization](https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization)